# interactive local bash cript, with argument, on remote server through ssh called by python

Tags: python, bash, ssh, scripting, openssh

I have a python script executing a local bash script on a remote host through ssh:

```
bash_script = "./ask_for_something.sh"
  os.system("ssh " + host + " bash -s -- " + argument + " < " + bash_script)
```

Using os.system because of [the third example here](http://www.bogotobogo.com/python/python_ssh_remote_run.php) The `argument` variable is of no consequence as it is acting as it should.

All is well until the bash script is at the point of asking for user input. Such as a confirmation to proceed, it ignores and moves forward.

I'm thinking it's got something to do with stdin but not getting where the problem is. I tried adding the -tt option to the ssh call but nothing seems to change.

I'd like to, at least, be able to make this work from the command line and deal with python afterwards.

I can use `ssh user@remote_server "$(< ./ask_for_something.sh)"` but can't send an argument.
Or `ssh user@remote_server bash -s -- argument < ./ask_for_something.sh` but then it's not interactive.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue is that bash's stdin, which is what ssh would be forwarding to you, is being taken up by the input redirection, `<`. This means that when the prompt happens it is already at "end of file", and so supplies an empty response.

Comment: I can use (https://serverfault.com/a/595256) Basically 'ssh user@remote_server "$(< localfile)"' But then I can't pass an argument. Not sure how else to do this...

Answer (score 0):

Basically gave up on this and scp'd the script over, then deleted it...

os.system("scp" + bash_script)

os.system('ssh ' + host; bash --login bash_script; rm bash_script --activate"')